# dismissViewControllerAnimated crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue

I have Simple popOver controller in my project. i can dismiss it using action button with following code.

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but sometimes app gets crash if i do something on that viewController 
before dismiss it.

**Example** : There is a pickerView for selection and post button. but without posting it if i did some selection and cancel it im getting this error. its only happening occasionally. not everytime. if it happens onetime then it might happen everytime after that.

Can someone explain? is it memory leak or something?

[image]

Comment: Please write crash log also?

Comment: On the Breakpoint pane of the Navigator panel (left-hand panel), set an Exception breakpoint and trigger the crash again.  It will show the line of code that triggered the exception, instead of the line of code where the exception was caught.

Comment: you mean like putting `@try` block for that dismiss?

Comment: Just copy the crash log and paste it into your question.

Comment: This is starting to look like a memory management issue.  Turn on zombie tracking and try again.  (Product->Scheme-Edit Scheme.  Click Diagnostics and check Enable zombie objects.)

Comment: @Avi i got this .  `-[ComposeViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7ce6f360`

Answer (score 0):

I think have solved the problem . in that PopOver new window i was using locationManager and i was using just
`[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`
but i have added following thing as well
   `locationManager = nil;`

no crash anymore

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you have dealloc function as mentioned below, this issue may occur.

```
- (void)dealloc {
      [_yourview release]; //don't do this
      [super dealloc];
}
```

I hope this might help some one else